# Uncaught TypeError: sweetalert2_react_content_1.default is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, sweetalert2

I have a react module where i am using TypeScript.

I want to use html within a Swal-component, and that just doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import withReactContent from "sweetalert2-react-content";

const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal);

MySwal.fire(<p>Holahola</p>);
```

When i hover the "Holahola" i get the error message: "Type 'Element' has no properties in common with type 'SweetAlertOptions'.ts(2769)".

When i try to run my code in Chrome, i get: "Uncaught TypeError: sweetalert2_react_content_1.default is not a function"

Someone got a clue what happens here?

I have also tried:

```
MySwal.fire({
    title: <p>Holahola</p>
})
```

Then i get this error: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's the known issue, you can subscribe to it here: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-react-content/issues/102

As a workaround, use `SweetAlertOptions` for passing the params:

```js
MySwal.fire({ 
  title: <p>Holahola</p> 
});
```

Comment: I've tried this one. See the updated post now above. Just seems like it cannot handle JSX-elements?

Comment: seems like you need to upgrade your deps to latest versions :)

Comment: We're using the latest versions of sweetalert2 and sweetalert2-react-content along with react 16.8.6 and react-dom 16.8.6. I don't see how that could be any issue like this one?

Comment: No, you don't. Spot the difference between your screenshot and https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/master/sweetalert2.d.ts#L23

Comment: Sorry. You were right about that. But now i have installed the latest sweetalert2, reinstalled all npm packages and my sweetalert2.d.ts is exactly like yours. Still getting an error message (see the updated post)

Comment: I can't help anymore without you making a test repository because what you're saying seems to be different from what you're coding :)

Comment: we have the test repo https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-webpack-demo which you can check out how sweetalert2 + sweetalert2-react-content are working well together